# Determining index with XPath

Tags: html, xpath

So given the following structure:

```
<div class="div">test
  <div class="div">test1
    <div class="div">test2</div></div></div>
<div class="div">test3</div>
<div class="div">test4</div>
```

I realize within Chrome's console I can enter the following to access the first node:

```
$x('//div[1]')
```

Any thoughts as to how I might go about directly accessing the element with value 'test2' or maybe thoughts in general as to how xpath goes about assigning indices to various elements?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is. There are several ways to select this node, use

```
$x('/div/div/div')
```

or

```
$x('//div[. = "test2"]')
```

It really depends on the *rest* of your document that you did not show. Also, answers are usually not "general thoughts" about the topic. What is it, specifically, that you need to know in regard to indices?